# How make ActionBarOverlay on android 5

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I what to make windowActionBarOverlay in android l, but blow statusbar
this is the theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme.TranslucentStatus" parent="AppTheme.Default">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

Here's the result 
http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/5f5f92d8gw1em88wdq4ilj20u01hc79v.jpg

how to make Toolbar blow status

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this document? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: yes,it make action bar blow statusbar, but this make statusbar not translucent, i want image fill statusbar

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/
that makes best of windowActionBarOverlay.